SQLite (WAL-mode): guarantees on availability of committed writes in subsequent read transactions
I am running SQLite in WAL mode.
I have 2 processes, with connections "X" and "Y". The following things happen in-order:

in connection X, a write transaction is committed
in connection Y, a read transaction is started

(in my setup I can be sure that the read transaction starts after the write transaction finishes through means outside of SQLite, i.e. by sending some signal between the 2 processes but only after a successful write)
Question: can I be sure that the read transaction on connection Y contains the results of the write in connection X?
The piece from the documentation which contains the best hint is

WAL mode permits simultaneous readers and writers. [..] In WAL mode, SQLite exhibits "snapshot isolation". When a read transaction starts, that reader continues to see an unchanging "snapshot" of the database file as it existed at the moment in time when the read transaction started.

(from https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html)
This could be understood to mean a "yes" on my original question, but only if "as it existed at the moment" means "including all committed transactions". This latter part is not (entirely) explicit in the quote though.
